# How to write a batch file that opens the command line and automatically executes commands in that command line?

Tags: python, batch-file, command-line, anaconda, txt

I have recently been trying to automate a process that I use to update sitemaps for two static GitHub websites that I manage. The process is a Python program that enters the `sitemap.xml` file and updates parts of it when needed.

In order to automate this process, I decided to write a batch script that could run the sitemap-updating program. However, I wanted to run the batch script on Anaconda Prompt since the `sqlite3` plugin has not been activated on the other command lines; it only works with Anaconda Prompt. Because of this, I decided to take an approach that opens the Anaconda Prompt command line and runs the commands one by one.

First, I had a text file that had command line code like this:

```
@echo off
pushd Desktop
py updateSitemap.py
```

Here is the actual batch script that I am trying to run:

```
@echo off
"Anaconda3 (64-bit)\Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda).lnk" < "sitemapUpdateCommands.txt"
```

According to the syntax, this should put all of the information from the text file into the command line, but that did not work.

Is there something that I am confused about? Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations on an interesting problem that you have attempted to solve yourself! My only recommendation for future postings is that phrases like "but that did not work" don't help readers to know **how** it didn't work. It's (almost) always best to include the exact text of any error messages OR provide the best evidence available for "it's not working". Possibly in your case you should say, the output file is empty. Keep posting and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

the anaconda prompt is just calling `cmd.exe` and activating the anaconda script in it, you can do that in your script, if `Anaconda3` is installed in `C:\ProgramData\` (default) the script will look as follows.

```
@echo off
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

or for your case

```
@echo off
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
call yourscript.bat
```

where `yourscript.bat` is the `.bat` script you are trying to have anaconda execute in its command prompt. (which calls your python script).

---

to activate a certain environment, put it at the end of you activate command as follows.

```
@echo off
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat myenv
call yourscript.bat
```